# why is Facebook nslog say unavailable on the device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

```
 -(IBAction)faceBook:(id)sender{

  if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]) {

SLComposeViewController *controller = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];

SLComposeViewControllerCompletionHandler myBlock = ^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result){
    if (result == SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled) {

        NSLog(@"Cancelled");

    } else

    {
        NSLog(@"Done");
    }

    [controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:Nil];
};
controller.completionHandler =myBlock;

[controller setInitialText:@"#VOX"];
[controller addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""]];
[controller addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@""]];

[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:Nil];

 }
  else{
NSLog(@"UnAvailable");
}

 }
```

Hello, I am trying to figure out why my iOS device says unavailable in nslog,but this method works perfectly on simulator.Can anyone confirm the service is down?

Comment: which OS do you have on device?

Comment: @Atif iOS lower than 6.0 would not recognize the Social framework.

Comment: @Stavash, yes you are correct. +1 for your answer :)

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you have no Facebook accounts set up on your device. As the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/SLComposeViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) states:

---

**isAvailableForServiceType**

Return Value
Returns a Boolean value indicating whether the service is accessible and at least one account is set up.